# Gmail PHP API Create Filter Issue

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

Am trying to use the official Gmail PHP Library to create a new label. I am using standard Oauth to authenticate the user (all necessary permissions have been given).

But I receive the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 &quot;error&quot;: {
  &quot;errors&quot;: [
   {
    &quot;domain&quot;: &quot;global&quot;,
    &quot;reason&quot;: &quot;invalidArgument&quot;,
    &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Filter doesn't have any actions&quot;
   }
  ],
  &quot;code&quot;: 400,
  &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Filter doesn't have any actions&quot;
 }
}
```

The code is as follows:

```
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($google);
$label = new Google_Service_Gmail_Label();
      $label->setId('Label_8');

      $label2 = new Google_Service_Gmail_Label();
      $label2->setId('UNREAD');

      $label3 = new Google_Service_Gmail_Label();
      $label3->setId('INBOX');

      $criteria = new Google_Service_Gmail_FilterCriteria();
      $criteria->setFrom('test@gmail.com');

      $action = new Google_Service_Gmail_FilterAction();
      $action->setAddLabelIds(array($label));
      $action->setRemoveLabelIds(array($label2,$label3));

      $filter = new Google_Service_Gmail_Filter();
      $filter->setCriteria($criteria);
      $filter->setAction($action);


      $result = $gmail->users_settings_filters->create('me',$filter);
```

Scopes being set:

```
$google->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub','https://mail.google.com','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'));
```

Everything looks fine programmatically. I even checked the code and it is assigning the actions. I believe there maybe something wrong with the library. Any advice will help.

Comment: If I perform the same using their API explorer at: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/create#try-it it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue by analyzing the logs:

```
  $action->setAddLabelIds(array($label));
  $action->setRemoveLabelIds(array($label2,$label3));
```

Should be:

```
  $action->setAddLabelIds(array('Label_8'));
  $action->setRemoveLabelIds(array('UNREAD','INBOX'));
```

Inconsistent API at the moment.